# Spring boot- inject service into doFiler

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to inject a auth service to a `Filter` -

```
@Autowired
AuthRequestService authService;
```

And use it in `doFiler` method -

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    System.out.println("SAPServiceFilter: "+ req.getRequestURI());
    //TODO - create auth sender
    authService.isAuthnticate((HttpServletRequest)request); //null
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

My filter class in sub-package of my `@SpringBootApplication` class and annotated with `@service` -

```
@Service
public class AuthRequestService {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("AuthRequestService @PostConstruct");
    }

    public boolean isAuthnticate(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("isAuthnticate");
        return true;
    }
}
```

The class also appears when listing all my beans using -

```
for (String name : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Still when debugging `authService` is null, one last thing the filter is registered with `FilterRegistrationBean` -

```
FilterRegistrationBean<SAPServiceFilter> filterRegBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
filterRegBean.setFilter(new SAPServiceFilter());
```

Comment: can you use `Interceptor` instead of `Filter`?

Comment: Yes, but what is the difference?

Comment: you can define the Interceptor as Spring bean and then inject any required service within interceptor

Comment: LOL - it is my question(this one) not a dup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use constructor injection. Supposed your filter registration bean lives in a component and has access to the service you could autowire it there and pass it with the constructor

```
@Autowired  
AuthRequestService authRequestService;

[...]

FilterRegistrationBean<SAPServiceFilter> filterRegBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
filterRegBean.setFilter(new SAPServiceFilter(authRequestService));
```

Comment: Works, but can you provide a more detailed reason?

Comment: Its pretty clear. If you need the service you can get it from the context through constructor injection. Read the spring manual, if that is all new to you

Comment: The filter is not within the spring context and therefore autowired injection is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter is not under the control of spring. That´s why the autowired dependencies  are not being injected.

In your filter init code add this line:

```
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
```

or

```
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this,getServletContext());
```

But there are more other ways to register a servlet filter in spring context:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-filters-listeners-beans